# Mongoose - Send message to websocket clients from other thread

Tags: multithreading, mongoose, websocket

I am using mongoose in a c++ application to provide a websocket server.
Now I would like to send a bigger amount of data to the connected
clients, triggered by the server itself.
The problem is that the server and the send (or broadcast) function run in different threads.
Does anybody know if there is a solution of synchronizing these two threads?

BR, M

Comment: I havent found a solution using mongoose so I wrote my own threadsafe websocket implementation.

Comment: Could you please share any link for your solution here? Thanks